# Yii2- insert value to text input field on button click via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, dynamicform

I am working on `yii2`. I have created a [dynamic](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform) form. I have some fields in it.

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <button type="button" id="addBtn" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
    <button type="button" id="remBtn" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <?= $form->field($modelTariffSlabs, "[{$i}]slab_name")->textInput(['readonly'=>true,'value'=>'S-1','maxlength' => 10]) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <?= $form->field($modelTariffSlabs, "[{$i}]slab_start")->textInput(['maxlength' => 10]) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <?= $form->field($modelTariffSlabs, "[{$i}]slab_end")->textInput(['maxlength' => 10]) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <?= $form->field($modelTariffSlabs, "[{$i}]rate")->textInput(['maxlength' => 10]) ?>
    </div>
</div><!-- .row -->
```

**GUI**

[image]

**What I want to do?**

I want to add the `Slab Name` automatically whenever I press the [image: addBtn]. So when the form is loaded for the first time the slab name should be `S-1`, when the add button is clicked and the new form is opened the slab name should be `S-2` and so on.

**Update 1**
I have tried the following

1. Declared and initialized a variable to `1`
2. Append this variable with the value

   ```
   <div class="col-sm-3">
                               <?= $form->field($modelTariffSlabs, "[{$i}]slab_name")->textInput(['readonly'=>true,'value'=>'S-'.$s,'maxlength' => 10]) ?>
                           </div>
   ```

I am able to get the value of text input via jquery.

```
$("#addBtn").click(function(e){
var value = $("#mdctariffslabs-0-slab_name").val();
alert(value);
    });
```

**Update 2**

I have tried @Yatin's solution

```
 <?= $form->field($modelTariffSlabs, "[{$i}]slab_name")->textInput(['readonly'=>true,'value'=>'S-1','maxlength' => 10,"class"=>"form-control js-slab-name"]) ?>

$("#addBtn").click(function(e)
{
  $(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) 
  {
    $(".dynamicform_wrapper .js-slab-name").each(function(index) {
    $(this).html("S-" + (index + 1));
   }); 
   });
   });
 });
```

Also, I have placed it outside the `addBtn`

```
$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) 
 {
    $(".dynamicform_wrapper .js-slab-name").each(function(index) {
    $(this).html("S-" + (index + 1));
   }); 
   });
   });
```

It still not working.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Can we see your attemps with onClick ?

Comment: @Sfili_81 please check my update 1

Comment: @Faisal Your update does not show any try to append a new row. My answer here may be help for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62856054/how-can-i-get-the-value-from-a-cell-in-a-table/62856591#62856591

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I will look into it. But I have a question. The input boxes are in a panel box. So every time when I click the add button a new panel is created

Comment: @Faisal my answer working with table rows. Also if you know Jquery, you will find the way how to track new panels and set a desired table row inputs needed properties.

Comment: @Faisal My answer is just a way how you can implement that, but not a solution for your problem.

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget, then below code should works,

Take widgetContainer class

```
<?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
        'widgetContainer' => "dynamicform_form_wrapper", <======= take class
        'widgetBody' => ".container-filter",
        'widgetItem' => ".filter-item",
        'limit' => 10,
        'min' => 1,
        'insertButton' => '.js-add-filter',
        'deleteButton' => '.js-remove-filter',
        'model' => $modelsCondition[0],
        'formId' => 'test-form',
        'formFields' => [
            'description'
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Add class to your input field - js-slab-name

```
<?= $form->field($modelTariffSlabs, "[{$i}]slab_name")->textInput(['readonly'=>true,'value'=>'S-1','maxlength' => 10,"class"=>"form-control js-slab-name"]) ?>
```

Jquery to set your slab_name incremental

```
jQuery(".dynamicform_form_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {
    console.log("after insert");
    jQuery(".dynamicform_form_wrapper .js-slab-name").each(function(index) {
                 console.log("set slab-name");
        jQuery(this).val("S-" + (index + 1));
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I have tried your code but still its not working `$("#addBtn").click(function(e){
   $(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {
    $(".dynamicform_wrapper .js-slab-name").each(function(index) {
        $(this).html("S-" + (index + 1));
    }); 
});
});`

Comment: @Faisal check updated jquery   jQuery(this).val("S-" + (index + 1));

Comment: can you please check my another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62928693/yii-2-dynamic-form-model-update-not-working) related to this widget?

Comment: Also I have added this new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62969155/jquery-add-1-against-each-text-input-in-yii2-dynamic-form) can you please see it?