# Jquery add 1 against each text input in yii2 dynamic form

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, dynamicform

I already have added one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62913626/yii2-insert-value-to-text-input-field-on-button-click-via-jquery/62956044?noredirect=1#comment111350167_62956044) related to it. But there is a little change this time.

I have a `readonly` text input with a default value `1`.

```
 <?= $form->field($modelTariffSlabs, "[{$i}]slab_start")->textInput(['readonly'=>true,'value'=>'1','maxlength' => 10,"class"=>"form-control js-slab-start"]) ?>
```

Also, I have another text input which I am getting from the user

```
  <?= $form->field($modelTariffSlabs, "[{$i}]slab_end")->textInput(['maxlength' => 10]) ?>
```

**What I want to do?**

Whenever I press the add button, I want to add `+1` to the `slab_end` text input and then assign it to my next `slab_start` input text.

**What I have tried?**

```
$("#addBtn").click(function(e)
{


$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {

$(".dynamicform_wrapper .js-slab-start").each(function(index) {
  
             var end = +$("#mdctariffslabs-0-slab_end").val()+1;
             
    $(this).val(end);
}); 
});
});
```

So I added `100` in `slab_end` input text, and when I press the add button It does add `1` in it but shows me `101` in my next `slab_start` and current `slab_start`.

**1st Input (Before pressing add button)**

[image]

**After pressing add button**

[image]

Here as shown in the above image. The start value of 1st level is changed when I press the add button also the start value has changed and the next value of start is `101` but on 3rd level, the start value should be `151` as I have added `150` in my previous end text input.

**Update 1**

Below is my `addBtn jquery` code

```
$("#addBtn").click(function(e)
{


$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {

   //console.log("after insert");
$(".dynamicform_wrapper .js-slab-name").each(function(index) {
             //console.log("set slab-name");
    $(this).val("S-" + (index + 1));
    
}); 

 var len = $(".dynamicform_wrapper .js-slab-end").length-1;
 console.log(len);  
 var slabEndValue = $(".dynamicform_wrapper .js-slab-end:eq("+len+")").val();

 slabEndValue = parseInt(slabEndValue);
 console.log(slabEndValue);
 $(".dynamicform_wrapper .js-slab-start:end").val(slabEndValue);

 });
 });
 });
```

**Update 2**

I have updated my code. Removed the `addBtn` event and simply placed the event `afterInsert` including the value incrementing logic. But still the result is same

```
<?PHP
$script = <<< JS
$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {

   //console.log("after insert");
$(".dynamicform_wrapper .js-slab-name").each(function(index) {
             //console.log("set slab-name");
    $(this).val("s-" + (index + 1));
    
}); 

 var len = $(".dynamicform_wrapper .js-slab-end").length-1;
 console.log(len);  
 var slabEndValue = $(".dynamicform_wrapper .js-slab-end:eq("+len+")").val();
 console.log(slabEndValue);
 slabEndValue = parseInt(slabEndValue);

 $(".dynamicform_wrapper .js-slab-start:end").val(slabEndValue);

 });

 $(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterDelete", function(e) {
 console.log("Deleted item!");
 });

 $(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("limitReached", function(e, item) {
 alert("Limit reached");
 });




 JS;
 $this->registerJs($script);
 ?>
```

**Update 3**

I have tried to run the `jquery` in the console window.

[image]

In the console, I am getting `100` but while in production I am getting nothing. Secondly, I want to `+1` the value entered in end text box

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: as you said your logic is working and use go to 2 or 1 (mean previous filled value) line and change end value, then what happen?

Comment: Show your init `html`, also explain the exact logic what you trying to get.

Comment: you are binding the `afterInsert` on every click which is technically wrong , your `afterInsert` should be outside the click binding

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes I have tried it outside the on click but still same result

Comment: @Faisal Please add a initial `HTML` code of the panel what you render from browser, with the wrapper `div` of all your panels.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco here is it [_form](https://newtextdocument.com/bae3a53943)

Comment: @Faisal show us already rendered form from browser console. I need `html`.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco you want inner HTML ?

Comment: @Faisal Yes, show me what you get after your init form is rendered. I need all html in your wrapper `div`.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco here is the rendered [html](https://newtextdocument.com/8df86c23c1)

Comment: @Faisal I'm confused with your question: there're 3 versions of code, 3+ times you're trying to explain the desired behavior. Also you've commented `your given example is working but I am still unable to figure it out with my issue.` on Serghei Leonenco's answer, but them something went off rails. And there is no [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you simplify your question? And MRE would be really helpful.

Comment: @x00 I am trying to `+1` the value of the end to the next start value. For example, if the end value entered is `100` then by clicking on the `Add` button the next start value would be `101` => `100+1` and vice versa. 

I have tried the given solution(s). But I am unable to add `+1`. Although it's working on browser console (mentioned in my update 3). I am stuck to it and don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

add class js-slab-end

```
<?= $form->field($modelTariffSlabs, "[{$i}]slab_end")->textInput(['maxlength' => 10,"class"=>"js-slab-end"]) ?>
```

Jquery

```
$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {

    //Get Second last slab-end
    var len = $(".dynamicform_wrapper .js-slab-end").length - 1;
    var slabEndValue = $(".dynamicform_wrapper .js-slab-end:eq("+len+")").val();
    
    slabEndValue = parseInt(slabEndValue);

    $(".dynamicform_wrapper .js-slab-start:last").val(slabEndValue);
    
});
```

Comment: `slabEndValue` is always empty. so no value is set for the start

Comment: are you there still?

Comment: `var slabEndValue = $(".dynamicform_wrapper .js-slab-end:eq("+len+")").val(); console.log(slabEndValue);` gives me empty result

Comment: `slabEndValue = parseInt(slabEndValue);
console.log(slabEndValue);` gives me `NaN`

Comment: I have added my whole code for `addBtn` please see it

Comment: add your code in afterInsert event : $(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {   });

Comment: yes, it is right. what is the value of len in console.log coming? I am trying to find second last element (slab end ) value then  trying to add it in last  start

Comment: also, I have changed :end to  :last in jquery change it in your code

Comment: I have shared my `console.log` which I have checked in my console window.

Comment: Secondly, I want to `+1` the value entered in the end text box and then to add to the next start value. For example, I have entered `100` in my end text box, so when clicking on the add button the start value should be `101`

Comment: `$(".dynamicform_wrapper .js-slab-start:last").val(slabEndValue);` gives `NaN` in start

Comment: check updated script : add class js-slab-end. I missed adding "class" key in form field

Comment: I have already added `"class"=>"form-control js-slab-end"`

Comment: Still same result

Comment: Here is the link of my [_form](https://newtextdocument.com/bae3a53943). Have a check into it as well

Comment: You can check my `_form` maybe I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

Here what i think you can do:

> This is a example how you can manage your problem

```js
$(document).on('click', '#add', function(e){
  //get current template for append element
  var newPanel = $('.container .panel').html();
  //get total of childrens
  let lastChild = $('.container .panel').length;
  //get current panel start value
  let lastStartVal = $(this).parent().parent().find('form input#start').val();
  //get current panel end value
  let lastEndVal = $(this).parent().parent().find('form input#end').val();
  //check if the value is equal, if not increase +1
  //if(!lastStartVal ||lastStartVal === lastEndVal) lastEndVal++;//Encrease last value if it is not changed
  //append new panel
  $('.container').append('<div id="panel-'+ lastChild +'" class="panel"></div>');
  //append new panel html
  $('#panel-'+ lastChild +'').append(newPanel);
  var newPanel = $('#panel-'+ lastChild);
  //set values
  lastEndVal++;
  newPanel.find('form input#start').val(lastEndVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="panel-0" class="panel">
    <div id="panel-header">
      Panel
      <button id="add">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div id="panel-body">
      <form>
        <input id="start" name="start" value="" placeholder="Start" />
        <input id="end" name="end" value=""  placeholder="End" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update** i would use solution of @Yatin Mistry  but with little changes:

```
$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {

    //Get Second last slab-end
    var len = $(".dynamicform_wrapper .container-items .item").length;
    var lastItemId = len - 1;
    var slabEndValue = $(".dynamicform_wrapper #mdctariffslabs-" + lastItemId + "-slab_end").val();
    //Check if the value is assigned
    if(!slabEndValue) slabEndValue = 0;
    //increase
    slabEndValue++;

    $(".dynamicform_wrapper .js-slab-start:last").val(slabEndValue);
    
});
```

Comment: I have run the snippet and entered 100 in end text box and then pressed the add button. The next start should 101 but it's still 100

Comment: Still the same result. It doesn't add +1 to the end value's

Comment: @Faisal I just checked and made it to be clear input names. Everything is working.

Comment: your given example is working but I am still unable to figure it out with my issue.

Comment: `var slabEndValue = $(".dynamicform_wrapper #mdctariffslabs-" + lastItemId + "-slab_end").val();
    console.log(slabEndValue);` gives me empty result. Morevoer the next start value is again set to `1`

Comment: @Faisal Have you typed anything in your initial input? Also i saw you have solved this issue in your other question is not it?

Comment: First time when I open my form, the value of start is always `1`. I entered `100` in my end text box then I entered rate. After clicking on `+` button the start value should be `101` i.e. `100+1` and so on

Comment: I don't know the reason but when I am checking it in my browser console. `$(".dynamicform_wrapper #mdctariffslabs-" + lastItemId + "-slab_end").val();` I am getting `100` but not in my code :(

Comment: It is hard for me to replicate same issue with this extension, but like i said, it is better to use @Yatin Mistry solution + my example to evaluate the desired result.

Comment: Yes i have tried both ways but still I am unable to get the desired result.